# Mux 2:1 with NAND gate and function generator

Tags: multiplexer, function-generator, nand

I want to simulate the operation of a 2:1 mux using only NAND gates. I want to insert two square wave signals and obtain the corresponding result depending on whether the selection is 0 or 1.

With the theoretical design, everything works fine in Multisim and data E0 and E1 are copied depending on whether voltage passes or not. However, when mounting it physically on a protoboard with a function generator, I don't get the copy and I don't know where the error is. I know I'm connecting the function generator wrong or something like this but I don't know what.

The equation for a 2:1 multiplexer and layout are fine:

[image: Multisim simulation]

Now, trying to do the theoretical thing with the function generator, I never get a response on the oscilloscope S that copies the data E0 or E1, neither in this simulator nor physically on the protoboard.

[image: What happens in real simulation..]

Where is the fault?

Comment: The pictures look fine. You want to first test and observe that pin 6 actually is the inverse of your SW. A voltmeter is sufficient for this. Try it, Verify. Next, if you have an oscilloscope in real life, test/observe that pin 3 or pin 9, with the switch `closed`, outputs 1 kHz, and that with the switch `open` that pin 10 or pin 11 outputs 10 kHz. If any of this fails, then work backwards from what you learn isn't working and solve it. Otherwise, you've proved that the switch and its inverter and the two enabling AND gates for each frequency are working. That leaves only the last gate, right?

Comment: For example, protoboards are notorious. It could be that the wire gauge you are using for jumpers is too slim and isn't always making the contact you wished (wobbles in the hole would be an indicator.) There could be dirt in some holes. Or oxidation. Etc. There's a host of possible problems. And we should probably also see a picture of what you actually did build.

Comment: I just [wired things up in Digital (Neemann's)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5koYA.png) and it all works just as expected. Just another test to be sure. I used your own wiring diagram in your second picture and used a 7400 device -- I didn't use abstract gates (as in your first picture) but instead the simulation of the IC behavior (as in your second picture.) So this goes against your second picture, which you say doesn't appear to work.